# IBM Worklight Adapter requires OAuth

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Here is my problem: I would like to create an application with IBM Worklight which will call via an adapter a service that requires OAuth (ie: Twitter).

Anyone have some thought for the best method to implement this using IBM Worklight?

For example, use one method to get the token, store the token in the session and then other methods to interact with the service?

Is there some out of the box functionality in IBM Worklight to handle the token acceptance in such case (ie: automatically open a browser to provide the authorization)?

Many thanks
Dominique

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cordova inappbrowser plugin to get the access token and pass the token to the Worklight adapters. I am working on a devworks article now with an example so I will update this response with a link once it's live.

Here's the link to the article that might be helpful to you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-worklight-linkedin/index.html